# Writing a C++ program that reads five integers and performs a few tasks

Tags: c++, function

I am trying to make a program that reads five integers and performs maximum, minimum, average, sum of negative integers, and sum of positive integers. The current issue is that the average turns out the same as the sum of the positive integers, of which the sum is lower than what it should be. Example: I inserted 5, 5, 5, 5, 1 integers. 16 comes out as the average, and 16 comes as the sum of all the positive integers.

```
int main()
{
    int min = 0, max = 0, num = 0, counter = 1, pos = 0, neg = 0;
    double total = 0;
    do {
        cout << "Enter in a number: ";
        cin >> num;
        if (num > max)
            max = num;
        if (num < min)
            min = num;
        if (num < 0) {
            neg += num;
        }
        if (num > 0) {
            pos += num;
        }
        total += num;
        counter++;
    } while (counter <= 5);

    total /= counter;
    cout << "Smallest Number of the list is: " << min << endl;
    cout << "Largest Number of the list is: " << max << endl;
    cout << "The sum of negative numbers is: " << neg << endl;
    cout << "The sum of positive numbers is: " << pos << endl;
    cout << "The average of all numbers is: " << total << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does `do not work` mean?

Comment: Did you insert exactly as 5,5,5,5,1 or did you insert 5 5 5 5 1 with whitespace between?

Comment: no whitespace @kingW3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated the code for you.  Learning to use a debugger is a worthwhile exercise, you can step through the code line by line to find the issue.  It is a great way to learn the language and save yourself hours of misery.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits> // INT_MAX, INT_MIN

using namespace std;
int main()
   {
//make min and max the opposite so the first number entered with replace both
    int min = INT_MAX, max = INT_MIN, num = 0, counter = 0, pos = 0, neg = 0;
    double total = 0;
    do {
        cout << "Enter in a number: ";
        cin >> num;
        if (num > max)
            max = num;
        if (num < min)
            min = num;
        if (num < 0) {
            neg += num;
        }
        if (num > 0) {
            pos += num;
        }
        total += num;
        counter++;
    } while (counter < 5);  // go from 0 to 4, ending with counter == 5
    total /= counter;
    cout << "Smallest Number of the list is: " << min << endl;
    cout << "Largest Number of the list is: " << max << endl;
    cout << "The sum of negative numbers is: " << neg << endl;
    cout << "The sum of positive numbers is: " << pos << endl;
    cout << "The average of all numbers is: " << total << endl;
    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of the variable counter equals 6 after the while loop, therefore the average is not correct. Either replace it with 5 or counter-1.

```
 total /= 5;
```

Or,

```
total /= (counter-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `total` as your average value:

Here you are summing up all your numbers: `total += num;`

Here you are printing the sum instead of an average:

`cout << "The average of all numbers is: " << total << endl;`

Instead, your print line should be:

`cout << "The average of all numbers is: " << total /= counter << endl;`

To elaborate, `total /= counter` will divide `total` by `counter` and set the new value to `total`.